# C# UWP app crashes if SecondaryTile Imagesources are not from Assets folder

Tags: c#, uwp, secondary-live-tile

Basically I'm trying to make an UWP app to create Custom Tiles on Start Menu.
The SecondaryTile is working when the Tile Images are from Assets folder like this.

```
Uri square150x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/square150x150Tile-sdk.png");
Uri wide310x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wide310x150Tile-sdk.png");
Uri square310x310Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/square310x310Tile-sdk.png");
Uri square30x30Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/square30x30Tile-sdk.png");
```

But I have images in ApplicationData folders and trying to use the path like this:

```
Uri square150x150Logo = new Uri(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path, "ImageSquare.png"));
Uri wide310x150Logo = new Uri(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path, "ImageWide.png"));
Uri square310x310Logo = new Uri(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path, "ImageLarge.png"));
Uri square30x30Logo = new Uri(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path, "ImageTiny.png"));
```

But this way the app is crashing. The debugger isn't working either. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally figured it out.
In Addition to Andrew's answer, I had to change to using the `LocalState` folder instead of the `TempState`.
Andrew directed in the right way to use `ms-appdata`, but for some reason `ms-appdata:///temp/` returned error. but using `ms-appdata:///Local/` solved the Issue.

Comment: For future reference, This answer is correct but have to use `Local` folder instead of `temp` in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To reference application data files, you should be using `ms-appdata:///`.

Calling `TemporaryFolder.Path` will return the absolute file path, `C:\`, which isn't allowed to be used on secondary tiles.

So your updated code would be...

```
Uri square150x150Logo = new Uri("ms-appdata:///temp/ImageSquare.png"));
```

Comment: Oh I see. Have to use uri. Makes sense.